# which of these async loading methods is the best? document write?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Is there difference between these two async JavaScript loading methods?

```html
<div class="g-plusone"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d, t) {
        var g = d.createElement(t),
            s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.async = true;
        g.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
    })(document, 'script');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function() {
        document.write('<fb:like href="http://www.sandrophoto.com/' + location.pathname + '" send="true" width="360" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>');
        var s = document.createElement('SCRIPT'),
            s1 = document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0];
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
        s1.parentNode.insertBefore(s, s1);
    })();
    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two look conceptually similar in loading.  They both create a new script tag and add it to the DOM which allows both to load asynchronously without dependencies on other script tags which must load in the order presented.  There are minor differences in these implementations, but they look conceptually the same from the loading point of view.

The document.write() in the FB code causes some serialization with other loading events and could slow it down slightly (depends upon circumstances).

Comment: Ok, per your suggestion I decided to remove document.write and write div inside html directly. As for the rest of the code, I went with option #1, seems less code to me :)

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious difference is that the document.write approach writes the code into the doc exactly where it's placed, wherein the other method places the content into the container div specified.

There are some other differences too, and some other ways of loading scripts asynchronously.

Steve Souders has written an excellent article on the topic, http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/, which I recommend reading.

Comment: But the document.write() has nothing to do with the script tag loading as best I can tell - it's just a FB tag (that the script itself may later use).  Do you think the document.write() is material to the script loading?

Comment: Ah yes you're quite right. The write in this case does not actually affect the loading of the script. You probably could just insert the tag manually into the page or whatever an achieve the exact same effect.